# PLINQ на 3.5 .net Framework

Tags: .net, распараллеливание, linq, plinq

Есть ли механизм использования plinq на платформе 3.5?
Как то сталкивался с использованием обычного linq на 2.0 используя linq bridge.
Найти что то подобное для plinq не смог.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открыть рефлектором код расширяющего метода для распараллеливания и скопировать.

В своё время мы использовали это:

```
private void ParallelFor(int from, int to, Action<int> body)
{
  int numProcs = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2 + 4;
  // количество оставшихся
  int remainingWorkItems = numProcs;
  int nextIteration = from - 1;

  ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(numProcs, numProcs);
  using (ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false))
  {
    for (int p = 0; p < numProcs; p++)
    {
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
      {
        int index = 0;
        while ((index = Interlocked.Increment(ref nextIteration)) < to)
          body(index);

        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref remainingWorkItems) == 0)
          mre.Set();
      });
    }

    // ждём, пока отработают все задания
    mre.WaitOne();
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, хорошая идея. Меня собственно интересует базовый метод AsParallel думаете его можно получить подобным образом?

Comment: Думаю, да.